# Heroku Scheduler for Discord bot to send daily message

Tags: heroku, discord.js

I currently have a discord.js bot hosted on Heroku. I want to schedule a daily message, but Heroku Scheduler takes a single `.js` file to run a scheduled task. If I were to schedule it, I would have to copy the basic code from my `index.js` and create another instance of the bot to send the scheduled message. Is there a better way to schedule a Discord message on Heroku?

Comment: You could use a different tool, such as [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron) which I believe will be a better fit for you in this scenario

Comment: Otherwise yes, you'll have to rework your file(s) to be able to run your index.js without other conflicts

Comment: I did initially try node-cron, but had issues with consistency due to the dynos being [cycled](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting)

Comment: What would happen if you scheduled the task with cron every 23h and 59m?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to keep it simple, you can use the Discord API directly, without discord.js. [Take a look at the documentation for the Create Message endpoint](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message). You can use a library like [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to make the request in your single scheduled `.js` file.

You can also use the [@discordjs/rest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@discordjs/rest) package, which allows you to more easily make requests to the Discord API without having to spin up an entire gateway-connected bot.